# Read More/Less with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, uitextview, expand

I want to add "**Read more**" at the end of the paragraph. When I click on the "Read more" text, it should be expand and display "**Less**" at the end. 
The texts will be collapsed when click on "Less" text.

[image]

I find many sample work in google. But, I don't understand clearly and most projects are implemented with Objective-C. I also find it in youtube.

 I would like know very sample code to implement this with **Swift 3**.

Can I implement without using any additional library?

 Please help me.

Comment: Do you want to implement into tableview cell ?

Comment: No bro @JeckyModi   . Currently, I add Label. This label is about movie review. I want to display the movie synopsis. Should I add Label or Text View for synopsis?
I don't put any table in this page.

Comment: No,its ok, below answer is right. Like if your paragraph lines above 5 lines then there should be a button for read more /less. If you want to do it in dynamic way then you have to find height of that label and increase height of that label as according to text

Comment: @JeckyModi bro.  You mean, To get dynamic view of Movie review label , firstly I should define the height of the label? But I could not know the maximum height of that label. Movie review text might have more than 3 paragraphs I think. So, if I define 300px label height, the text will not be show up if the height is more than 300px. Isn't it? How to do? I'm sorry I don't know how to solve this exactly. :(

Comment: No, i dont mean like that. When you set text to label then U have to find height of label then assign that height to label with setting property number of lines = 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Create an outlet for height constraint of your `messageLabel`
- Set top layout of your "Read more" button to `messageLabel`
- On clicking "Read more" button increase height constraint constant, on clicking "Read less" decrease height constraint constant.

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

  @IBOutlet weak var lblHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

  var isLabelAtMaxHeight = false

  @IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
      if isLabelAtMaxHeight {
          btn.setTitle("Read more", for: .normal)
          isLabelAtMaxHeight = false
          lblHeight.constant = 70
      }
      else {
          btn.setTitle("Read less", for: .normal)
          isLabelAtMaxHeight = true
          lblHeight.constant = getLabelHeight(text: yourSummaryText, width: view.bounds.width, font: yourSummaryLabel.font)
      }
  }
  ```

Get height of a text

```
    func getLabelHeight(text: String, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let lbl = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        lbl.frame.size.width = width
        lbl.font = font
        lbl.numberOfLines = 0
        lbl.text = text
        lbl.sizeToFit()

        return lbl.frame.size.height
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for instant feedback. I will try to test your code.

Comment: This is for a normal label and button in your view. If you want to use it in your table/collection views, you have to update cell heights/widths as well.

Comment: Bro @Matt,  You mean to get dynamic view of Movie review label , firstly I should define the height of the label? But I could not know the maximum height of that label. Movie review text might have more than 3 paragraphs I think. So, if I define 300px label height, the text will not be show up if the height is more than 300px. Isn't it?
How to do? I'm sorry I don't know how to solve this exactly. :(

Comment: Did you placed those labels in a view? or a table/scrollview?

Comment: I put scrollview and put labels in it. bro

Comment: I'll suggest a tableview though. Anyway, height of the label does not matter here. Other controls in a scroll view will be aligned to give label's space. You just have to set its height constraint accordingly. Check edited answer to get possible height for a text.

Comment: bro @Matt, I add the text-->  ` lblReview.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ex augue, ullamcorper eu lacus ut, dignissim aliquet eros. Praesent ultricies porttitor urna quis iaculis. Aenean vitae nulla in ipsum facilisis placerat. ONCE upon a time there were four little Rabbits, and their names were— Flopsy, Mopsy, Cotton-tail, and Peter.They lived with their Mother in a sand-bank, underneath the root of a very big fir tree.". `

According to your code, ---> should I put these texts into  "yourSummaryText"? isn't it?

Comment: yes or just pass lblReview.text if text is already set and font is lblReview.font

Comment: Bro @Matt, I did what you said. All are working well but I put "\n" in my text so the texts are not show completely. A few 3 to 4 words left to show. Could you please tell me how to do it bro?

Comment: It will work with "\n". If the issue is missing of 3/4 words then do this. If width of the label is 300, pass 280 in getLabelHeight function. You will get a little more height than usual, which should be enough.

Comment: Bro @Matt, I really really thank you for helping me whenever, whatever I ask you. Now, I can see all the words. I changed Line Break: "Character Wrap " in Attributes Inspector. :) :)

Comment: bro could you please take a look at to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966983/how-to-set-label-height-for-auto-adjust-in-read-more-less-with-swift-3/44967866?noredirect=1#comment76911366_44967866 ?

Comment: @MayPhyu.. did u got solution for this ?
am also stucked in this ?
Where we need to create btn ? and how it will come at the end of the text ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with trimming the string.

we can compare the string characters length by .count and we can hide read more button if there are less only very few characters in the string.

And removed the last word after trimming to ensure that no visible words are cut off. Then added "...." at the end

```
        var trimData = ""

        if eventData.eventDescription.count > 500 {
            cell.readMoreLabel.isHidden = false

            if !readMore {

                if eventData.eventDescription.count > 500 {

                    trimData = String(eventData.eventDescription.prefix(500))

                    trimData = trimData.components(separatedBy: " ").dropLast().joined(separator: " ")

                    trimData = trimData+"...."
                } else {
                    trimData = eventData.eventDescription
                }

                cell.readMoreLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Read More", attributes:
                    [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue])



            } else {
                trimData = eventData.eventDescription
                cell.readMoreLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Read Less", attributes:
                    [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue])
            }

        } else {
            trimData = eventData.eventDescription
             cell.readMoreLabel.isHidden = true
        }
```