# Read More Button in UILabel in UITableViewCell with Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3, tablecell

I would like to expand the label when I click on ReadMore button. 
I added a Label within the table cell. 
I don't want to have scroll style within label because I already added scrollview to ViewController. So, there will be scroll within scroll. So, it is not convenient to scroll. 
 I just want to fit the label height with table row height.
I added the following code in **Readmore button Action** event.

```
MovieInfoTable.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
MovieInfoTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

But, this is not working. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: When click on read more ,get label height with respect to more text and reload table.

Comment: You need to increase the height dynamically of that cell when you click Read more.

Comment: For the future viewers, this is exactly what you are looking for: https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reload the tableView in button action.

```
MovieInfoTable.reloadData()
```

Also set a boolean value, like readMoreButtonClicked = true, to show that button has been clicked.

And in the tableView delegate methods,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if readMoreButtonClicked {
       return 68
    }
    return 40
}
```

Comment: Bro @Sneha, bro I don't want to have scroll bar within table cell. Actually, I tried with another way. This is my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338768/read-more-less-with-swift-3/42338894?noredirect=1#comment71875123_42338894. Could you kindly please take a look? I prefer with the first way.

Comment: I would suggest you to have a single tableview instead of a scrollview and a tableview.

Comment: Yes bro @Sneha.

Comment: @MayPhyu Make this a tableview and try the answer I said.