# How to set label height for auto adjust in Read More/Less with Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I would like to create the paragraph with Read More/Read Less at the end. 
 Here are my codes;

```
func getLabelHeight(text: String, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {

    let lbl = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    lbl.frame.size.width = width
    lbl.font = font
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0
    lbl.text = text
    lbl.sizeToFit()
    lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    return lbl.frame.size.height

}
```

```
 @IBAction func btnReadMore(_ sender: Any) {
    if isLabelAtMaxHeight {

        btnReadmore.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Read more", comment: ""), for: .normal)
        btnReadmore.titleLabel!.font = UIFont (name: "Tharlon", size: 13)
        isLabelAtMaxHeight = false
        lblReviewHeight.constant = 29
        lblReview.font = UIFont (name: "Tharlon", size: 13)


    }
    else {

        btnReadmore.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Read less", comment: ""), for: .normal)
        btnReadmore.titleLabel!.font = UIFont (name: "Tharlon", size: 13)
        isLabelAtMaxHeight = true
        lblReviewHeight.constant = getLabelHeight(text: lblReview.text!, width: view.bounds.width, font: lblReview.font)
        lblReview.font = UIFont (name: "Tharlon", size: 13)
        lblReview.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingHead

    }

}
```

I also set the label "Word wrap" in Attributes Inspector. 
The problem is that when I add **"NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingHead"** in Read Less part, all the texts show completely. But, some words in those places inside text disappear.

So, I remove that code and run the app. At that time, texts are not shown completely and only show half. I've been trying to solve this problem the whole day. 
I don't want to use any other library. 
 
Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove constraint `lblReviewHeight`, then just try to use `numberOfLines` control your text layout, if your want show all description set `numberOfLines = 0`, otherwise set `numberOfLines` to the line you want.

Comment: bro   I could not remove lblReviewHeight because it controls the height of the label when I click on Read more/less button.

Comment: @MayPhyu auto layout will automatically calculate the height for us if you have a right constraint of that label, that means if your label have correctly constraints of `width` or `leading` `trailing` or `left` `right` or gives a `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` you will get a `best` size of this label.

Answer (score 0):

to calculate text height by font and width you can use this extension

```
extension UIFont {
func sizeOfString (_ string: String, constrainedToWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    return NSString(string: string).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                                         options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                                         attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: self],
                                                         context: nil).size
}
}
```

then call it

```
let width = 290.0
let textSize = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15).sizeOfString("text", constrainedToWidth: width)
```

Comment: bro @VadimKozak,  bro which code should I remove or replace in my codes bro?